# Is there any online resource where I download .pix PCIDSK raster file

Tags: raster

I need a sample .pix file for initial testing however could not find any online resource for the same.

Comment: Not sure why, but, requests for data sources are considered off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few .pix files in the GDAL sources. They are used for the autotests of the PCIDSK driver.

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/ccb472aed28de2b3d4c90ecbac05537b167b4220/autotest/gdrivers/data/pcidsk

The test images are not so attractive as images but they are in the right format and usable for testing if your client can read the format. The tile_v2 image looks like this

[image]